# PN junction basics: why is there diffusion to create depletion initially?

Tags: condensed-matter, semiconductor-physics

I consider two doping N and P materials.

N and P are **neutral**, but N is composed of impurities that increase the number of free electron. P is composed of impurities that increase the number of holes.

When we put N and P together, what is said is that the extra electrons from N would move to combine with hole in P. And it will create the depletion region.

What I don't understand is what initiate this motion initially. Indeed, everything being neutral there is no reason for such motion initially.

I barely have understood that there is some competition between the diffusion that is initially created and the electric fields created when the depletion region has been made. What are the mechanisms explaining this diffusion ?

[edit] To make my question more precise: what is the simplest model showing the equations governing the diffusion vs electrostatic forces in this ?

Comment: Diffusion occurs even in absence of electric field - due to the disparities in the concentration and random thermal motion.

Comment: @Vadim is it possible to have some basic equation explaining this diffusion process ? Because from "naive" maxwell equation I really don't understand how it can appear. Thanks !

Comment: It is diffusion, it has to do with the gradient of concentration, not the Maxwell equations. Maxwell equations result in the other component of the current (as you noted in your question).

Comment: @Vadim I edited.

Answer (score 0):

Diffusion is a process in which particles move according to their concentration gradient(Higher concentration to lower concentration). It happens because particles have to align evenly in-order to minimize the energy of the system.

Comment: Diffusion is always happening, even when there is no concentration gradient. It is just that then there is no _net_ movement of particles.

Answer (score 0):

If your junction is at a temperature $T>0 K$ how certainly it will be because of the third principle of tdm, then the free electrons in the N doped region are moving randomly inside the semiconductor; the same is true for the holes in the P doped region.  When you join the two regions, there will be some free electrons which will move from the N zone to the P, occupying a hole. This process is early stopped by the electric field which is generated by the donor ions near the contact surface. Indeed this electric field generates an energetic barrier which makes harder for electrons to go in the other region; this doesn't mean that there are not electrons that are able to go from the n to the p region, but only the more energetic are able to do so.